# Shortening or omitting namespace for enum in OData filter

Tags: c#, odata

I took a look at [[Tutorial & Sample] Use Enumeration types in OData](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/18/use-enumeration-types-in-odata.aspx) to see how I could filter data returned by OData using an enumeration. The data model I'm using has a long namespace, and it would be nice to be able to use something shorter, rather than

```
Organization.Office.Project.DomainObjects.Enumerations.MyEnumeration'MyValue'
```

it'd be nice to be able to just to do `MyEnumeration'MyValue'`. *How can I do this?* I tried setting the `Namespace` property of the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`, but it had no effect.

Comment: Does it allow you to do and Imports Organization.Office.Project.DomainObjects.Enumerations at the top of you code file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API OData supports the enum prefix free. I think that's you're looking for.

With enum prefix free enabled, you can directly use the enum value, for example,

`'MyValue'`

Below is the sample codes how to enable the enum prefix free. http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#06-01-custom-url-parsing

Below's the corresponding end to end test cases provided by OData team:

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/UriParserExtension/EnumPrefixFreeTest.cs

Below is the more detail introduction about the Uri parser extension.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/09/12/tutorial-amp-sample-odatauriparser-extension-support.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Sam Xu.  I edited your answer to include the code that worked for me.

Comment: Could you consider updating your answer to the newer `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` package? Also, I'd strongly suggest adding the relevant information from the links as part of your answer as that will make it much easier to immediately see and won't create a dependency with potentially dead links later on.